# Linux and real-time signals

Tags: c, linux, signals

I am trying to write simple program that uses real-time signals in Linux. But I encountered strange behaviour, first the code:

```
#include<signal.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include"errhandling.h"
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void baz(int sig,siginfo_t* info,void *context)
{
  if (sig==SIGUSR1)
      printf("SIGUSR1 %d\n",info->si_value.sival_int);
  else if(sig==SIGRTMIN)
      printf("SIGRTMIN %d\n",info->si_value.sival_int);
  else 
      printf("SIGRTMIN+1 %d\n",info->si_value.sival_int);
  return ;
}

void sig_output()
{
  sigset_t set;
  sigprocmask(0,NULL,&set);
  printf("blokowane sa: ");
  if (sigismember(&set,SIGUSR1))
      printf("SIGUSR1 ");
  if(sigismember(&set,SIGUSR2))
      printf(" SIGUSR2");
  printf("\n");
  return ;
}


int received=0;
int usr2=0;

void foo(int sig)
{
  return ;
}

void usr1_handler(int sig)
{
  printf("usr1_handler\n");
  //++received;
}



void usr2_handler(int sig)
{
  usr2=1;
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  int i=0;
  pid_t pid=getppid();
  struct sigaction a;
  struct sigaction a2;
  a.sa_flags=SA_SIGINFO;
  sigset_t set;
  sigemptyset(&set);
  //sigaddset(&set,SIGRTMAX);
  sigemptyset(&(a.sa_mask));
  sigemptyset(&(a2.sa_mask));
  a.sa_sigaction=baz;
  sigaction(SIGRTMIN,&a,NULL);
  a2.sa_handler=usr1_handler;
  sigaction(SIGRTMIN+1,&a2,NULL);
  //sigprocmask(SIG_SET,&(a.sa_mask),NULL);
  while(!usr2)
  {
      printf("while\n"); 
      sigsuspend(&set);

  }
      //pause()
  printf("after while\n");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

when I run this program and it enters this loop with sigsuspend and I send to this program SIGRTMIN everything goes ok - handler executes and it waits for another signal, but when I send it SIGRTMIN+1 I get segmentation fault.

It seems that for real-time signals I need to use this extended handler with 3 arguments, but why? Is it specified somewhere? I run this program on my friend OpenSUSE 12.1 and I don't get segmentation fault for SIGRTMIN+1, but on my Xubuntu 11.10, when I send SIGRTMIN+1 I am getting segmentation fault. Is it problem with my system? Or is it implementation dependent?

Comment: Lesson 1: don't use printf() in a signal handler.

Comment: I know about this - this is only out of frustration, because I wanted to get some info - if he enters my signal handlers.

Comment: Replace it by a vsnprintf() into a local buffer and a write() and you'll be probably okay.

Comment: Does it work if you set `SA_SIGINFO` and use the extended (three parameter) handler?

Comment: @alk - yes it works with SA_SIGINFO

Comment: What is in this "errhandling.h" include? Is ist necessary?

Comment: The above code also works under 64bit `Debian`.

Comment: Does it crash without the `printf()`s inside the signal handlers?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are missing to assign a handler to `a2.sa_sigaction`.

---

In general it is not good idea to refer to signals by a raw integer values, as the definition for the various signals might be platform specific.

---

`Update:` Make sure the `struct sigaction` structures are initialised properly by for example `memset()`ing them to 0.

Comment: You are right - it went missing during copying code, I changed first post, still I get segmentation fault for SIGRTMIN+1

Answer (score 1):

Don't use printf() and friends from inside a signal handler. Don't be stubborn... Here's a substitute.

```
#include <stdarg.h>

int myprintf(const char *fmt, ...);
int myprintf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    char buff[512];
    int rc;

    va_start( args, fmt );

    rc = vsnprintf ( buff, sizeof buff, fmt, args );
    va_end (args);

    if (rc >0 && rc < sizeof buff) write(1, buff, rc);

    return rc;
}
```

UPDATE: this appears to work:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma #include"errhandling.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int myprintf(const char *fmt, ...);
int myprintf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  char buff[512];
  int rc;

  va_start( args, fmt );
  rc = vsnprintf ( buff, sizeof buff, fmt, args );
  va_end (args);

  if (rc > 0 && rc < sizeof buff) write(1, buff, rc);

  return rc;
}

void baz(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
#define INFO_VAL(p) p?p->si_value.sival_int:0
  if (sig==SIGUSR1)
      myprintf("SIGUSR1 %d\n", INFO_VAL(info) );
  else if(sig==SIGRTMIN)
      myprintf("SIGRTMIN %d\n", INFO_VAL(info) );
  else
      myprintf("SIGRTMIN%+d %p\n", sig-SIGRTMIN, INFO_VAL(info) );
  return ;
#undef INFO_VAL
}

void sig_output()
{
  sigset_t set;
  sigprocmask(0,NULL,&set);
  myprintf("blokowane sa: ");
  if (sigismember(&set,SIGUSR1))
      myprintf("SIGUSR1 ");
  if(sigismember(&set,SIGUSR2))
      myprintf(" SIGUSR2");
  myprintf("\n");
  return ;
}
volatile int received=0;
volatile int usr2=0;

void foo(int sig)
{
  return ;
}

void usr1_handler(int sig)
{
  myprintf("usr1_handler\n");
  //++received;
}



void usr2_handler(int sig)
{
  usr2=1;
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  int i=0;
  pid_t pid=getppid();
  struct sigaction a, a2;
  sigset_t set;

  sigemptyset(&set);
  //sigaddset(&set,SIGRTMAX);
  sigemptyset(&a.sa_mask);
  sigemptyset(&a2.sa_mask);
  a.sa_flags = 0;
  a2.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
  a2.sa_sigaction = baz;
  a.sa_handler = usr1_handler;
  sigaction(SIGUSR1,&a,NULL);

  a.sa_handler = usr2_handler;
  sigaction(SIGUSR2,&a,NULL);

  sigaction(SIGRTMIN+1,&a2,NULL);
  sigaction(SIGRTMIN+2,&a2,NULL);
  sigaction(SIGRTMIN+3,&a2,NULL);
  //sigprocmask(SIG_SET,&(a.sa_mask),NULL);
  while(!usr2)
  {
      myprintf("while(!usr2)\n");
      sigsuspend(&set);

  }
      //pause()
  myprintf("after while\n");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I bet this `a.sa_flags = 0;` did the job.

Comment: Yes, metoo. I saw in in your answer while I already had put it into my local copy of the offending program. (the handling of a and a2 differed in a few too many places)

Comment: This does not help. `snprintf` is not specified to be async-signal-safe either, and in the real world (e.g. glibc) it's very async-signal-unsafe (it even calls `malloc`). Ideally `snprintf` *should be* specified as async-signal-safe, but getting everyone to fix their bad implementations is no easy task...

Comment: The OP is always free to supply his own replacement for vsnprintf(), IIRC, the Apache team was forced to do this in the days when snprintf() and friends were not yet present on every platform.