# Why recv returns -1 and errno=EINTR when set SO_RCVTIMEO?

Tags: c++, linux, recv, setsockopt

This problem only hapens when socket is set timeout with SO_RCVTIMEO.

`recv` should block for 3sec. But it returns because of EINTR as soon as another thread starts.

If I run thread `t2`, `recv` in thread `t1` will return `-1` without blocking and sets `errno` to `EINTR`.

But `recv` in thread `t1` functions normally when thread `t2` is not started, it just blocks for 3 seconds.

If thread `t2` runs before thread `t1`, `recv` also works properly.

I found it fails every time when I was debuging with SlickEdit or gdb. But works properly when it runs in terminal.

Here is code:

test.cpp:     link `-pthread` to use `<thread>` or thread throws exception

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<thread>

int socket_fd;
sockaddr_in server_addr;

void recvThread()
{
    char pData[4096];
    int len = recv(socket_fd,pData,4096,0);
    if(len<=0)
    {
        printf("len:%d\n",len);
        printf("errno:%d\n",errno);
    }
}

void otherThread()
{
    while(1)
    {
         sleep(1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    hostent *host;
    if((host=gethostbyname("127.0.0.1"))==NULL)
    {
         return 1;
    }
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
    server_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port=htons(8887);
    server_addr.sin_addr=*((in_addr*)host->h_addr);
    bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8);

    socket_fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    timeval timeout = {3,0};
    setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeval));
    if(connect(socket_fd, (sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr))<0)
    {
         return 1;
    }

    std::thread t1(recvThread);
    std::thread t2(otherThread);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: Do you know what `EINTR` *means*? Please start by reading [the `recv` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html).

Comment: I don't know why it is interrupted by a signal? std::thread t2(otherThread) call will send a signal?

Comment: If your second thread does nothing like shown in the question, that won't cause a signal to be sent to your process (but it will lead to wasting a lot of CPU cycles). It can be *any* signal, and there's simply no way for us to know anything more without a proper [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I updated all code there. Since I can't copy from inner machine, so there might be some typing mistakes. This code can present what i asked.

Comment: The weird part is: by exchanging the calling order of std:thread t1 t2, recv can be works well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Signals are used all over within threading internals. Don't be surprised if you get peripheral evidence of a signal without actually seeing it.

Comment: @o11c How should I deal with it? I just want recv() block for 3sec.

Comment: You check how much time passed, and wait for the remaining amount. Assuming, of course, that the signal wasn't one that *deliberately* said "go back to the event loop and do something else"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comment on EINTR from "Some programmer dude"

The debugger (gdb), unless can set/modify breakpoints asynchronously, needs to stop the target (your task), set the breakpoints, then resume it.
To stop it it could send SIGINT, which would thus cause EINTR on your system blocked calls.

If you using GNU C library you could use TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY macro, see this post:
[TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY and __USE_GNU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302547/temp-failure-retry-and-use-gnu)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential bug

```
bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8);
```

should be

```
bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero), sizeof(server_addr.sin_zero));
```

Add signal handlers to find out what the error is, for [linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) there is a method to handle all, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10209415/4013258).

Comment: And the `bzero` call isn't even needed after the previous `memset` call.

Comment: I removed bzero but nothing changed.

Comment: I tried some ways to make it work. Even sleep(1) after std::thread t1, and recv block 1sec, then recv return -1 when t2 started.

Comment: I found it fails every time when I was debuging with SlickEdit or gdb. But works properly when it runs in terminal.